# Difference between "Matériel de pêche", "Attirail de pêche"

Tags: sens, usage

Is there in fact a meaningful difference between "Matériel de pêche" and "Attirail de pêche", or are they more or less synonymous, like "fishing gear" and "fishing equipment"? Which would a rod-and-line angler be more likely to carry?

Comment: [The image in this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fishing_tackle) captures pretty well (though probably unintentionally) the slightly pejorative/‘poking  fun at’ notion that's often present when “attirail” is used in French. This image (& “attirail”) make me think of a ”city slicker” who’s bought all the latest expensive fishing gadgets/paraphernalia on the market (to impress fishing buddies rather than to catch fish?) when the only tackle/gear/equipment (matériel/équipement de pêche) really needed is [shown here](http://www.floridasportsman.com/2016/01/19/un-reel-cane-pole-fishing/).

Comment: Attirail is like unneeded stuff. :) As show in the image in the article.

Comment: Your picture is worth a thousand words, Papa Poule!

Comment: correction: as shown in the article. The Brits say kit for gear. Unwieldy kit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Un attirail* is usually really cumbersome. Most of the French will actually use it in a pejorative way.

When you show up with a ton of unecessary stuff, you will be welcomed with a :

> Mais qu'est ce que c'est que tout cet attirail !

Comment: Yes, exactly. cumbersome gear.

Answer (score 3):

In *attirail*, there is the idea that it is a lot of stuff, and that it is not so practical. It is mostly ironic. *Matériel* is more factual.

Comment: Thanks, Distic. So would Attirail refer more to the gear that a fishing trawler might use?

Comment: Not at all. I think it would not be used for professional fishing.